# Json Schema Date validaiton

Tags: c#, .net, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using JSON.Schema validation of my payload. One of the fields being date have the following json schema.

```
    "Date": {            
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Value": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            }
        },
        "required": [ "Value" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
```

On my server side (WEB API C#) I am validating the json as follows.

```
var schema = JSchema.Parse(jsonSchema);
var livestockRow = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
IList<ValidationError> errorMessages;
livestockRow.IsValid(schema, out errorMessages);
```

I pass my date as "24/09/2012" and it comes back as the below error:

```
String '24/09/2012' does not validate against format 'date'.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is expected to be in format *yyyy-MM-dd* when `"format": "date"` is specified.

If you want to validate it against another format you can define custom validator:

```
public class CustomDateValidator : JsonValidator
{
    public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
    {
        if (value.Type != JTokenType.String)
        {
            return;
        }

        var stringValue = value.ToString();
        DateTime date;
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(stringValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            context.RaiseError($"Text '{stringValue}' is not a valid date.");
        }
    }

    public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema) => schema.Format == "custom-date";
}
```

Use it in schema definition: `"format": "custom-date"` and in schema reader settings:

```
var schema = JSchema.Parse(jsonSchema, new JSchemaReaderSettings { Validators = new JsonValidator[] { new CustomDateValidator() } });
```

Comment: I switched to 2021/02/20 and it didn't like that, either